# Segmentation fault for simple memory allocation

Tags: c

I am trying to allocate memory using malloc to my int pointer. I get a segmentation fault and when I try to debug it using gdb I get this output:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00007ffff7a97f90 in __GI___libc_realloc (oldmem=0x7fffffffdfd0, bytes=1) at malloc.c:3015
>   3015    malloc.c: No such file or directory.

Code is as below:

```
int stringAllocation(char **destination){
    char c=1, *temp;
    int ctr=0;
    int num_of_char=0;

    while(c!='\n'){
        c=getc(stdin);
        num_of_char+=1;

        temp=realloc(*destination, sizeof(char)*num_of_char);
            if(temp)
                *destination=temp;
            else{
                printf("String allocation failure.");
                return -1;
            }

    *(*destination+ctr)=c;
    ctr++;
    }

    if((*destination)[ctr-1]=='\n')
        (*destination)[ctr-1]='\0';   
}
 main(void){

 char *temp_course;
 int temp_sem;
 int temp_acad_year;
 int valid=0;
 char dummy;
 int ctr;

 while(valid==0){
     dummy=0;
     while(dummy!='\n')
         dummy=getc(stdin);

     printf("\nGetting course!\n");

     printf("\nCourse code: "); 
     stringAllocation(&temp_course);

     printf("Semester: ");
     scanf("%d", &temp_sem);
         if(temp_sem<1||temp_sem>3){
             valid=0;
             continue;
         }
         else
             valid=1;

         printf("Academic year: ");
         scanf("%d", &temp_acad_year);
         if(temp_acad_year<1908||temp_acad_year>2015){
             valid=0;
             continue;
         }
         else
         valid=1                   
}

int numstud;
int *studnum;

valid=0;
while(valid==0){
    printf("Input number of students: ");

    scanf("%d", &numstud);

    if(numstud>=5&&numstud<=15)
         valid=1;
}

studnum=(int*)calloc(numstud,sizeof(int));
}             
}
```

Comment: "You want code with that?"

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.  Now please tell what you want from us?  You haven't posted any code, so you cannot expect any help.

Comment: Its like trying to solve the mystery of GOD, without seeing or meeting Him. :}

Comment: edited the post :)

Comment: @Haris you just need to have faith in you god.  Your god has faith in gdb.

Comment: Your example code is incomplete, please make it complete

Comment: @MartinJames, Why not put your faith directly on gdb. :}

Comment: I don't need faith to test such code, just a compiler.  Seems to run OK for me:)

Comment: @MartinJames, Believing that the compiler would pick up potential errors is nothing but faith, :p

BTW, the code looks correct. True that. :}

Comment: Example code edited. Sorry!

Comment: Not your original bug, but you are assigning the result of getc to a char.  Don't do that, it returns int for a reason.  Check for EOF before assigning it to a char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

temp_course was not initialised.  So when its existing value is used in the call to reallocate, your code crashes.  Initialise it to NULL.